# New column based to boost entries who have raced with other entries in this race in the past

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following large dataset recording the result of a math competition among students in descending order of date: So for example, student 1 comes third in Race 1 while student 3 won Race 2, etc.

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank  
1         1/1/2023       1               3     
1         1/1/2023       2               2     
1         1/1/2023       3               1     
1         1/1/2023       4               4     
2         11/9/2022      1               2     
2         11/9/2022      2               3     
2         11/9/2022      3               1     
3         17/4/2022      5               4     
3         17/4/2022      2               1     
3         17/4/2022      3               2     
3         17/4/2022      4               3     
4         1/3/2022       1               1     
4         1/3/2022       2               2     
5         1/1/2021       1               2     
5         1/1/2021       2               3     
5         1/1/2021       3               1
```

I want to add a new column called "Competitor" which is a recency weighted of the rank difference with all other students in this student's past races give by the formula:
1/(date@ today's race - date@race t-1)( sum of (Student's rank @ race t-1 - rank @ t-1 of students of current race))

So the desired column looks like this:

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      Rank    Competitor
1         1/1/2023       1               3       -0.003268 =(1/112)((2-3)+(2-1))+(1/259)(0)+(1/306)(1-2)+(1/730)((2-3)+(2-1))
1         1/1/2023       2               2       0.03150884
1         1/1/2023       3               1       -0.0308953
1         1/1/2023       4               4       0.01158301
2         11/9/2022      1               2       -0.0051546
2         11/9/2022      2               3       0.00320629
2         11/9/2022      3               1       -0.0048544
3         17/4/2022      5               4       0
3         17/4/2022      2               1       0.02764602
3         17/4/2022      3               2       -0.0063694
3         17/4/2022      4               3       0
4         1/3/2022       1               1       -0.0023585 
4         1/3/2022       2               2       0.00235849
5         1/1/2021       1               2       0
5         1/1/2021       2               3       0
5         1/1/2021       3               1       0
```

So for example for the first entry: -0.003268 =(1/112)((2-3)+(2-1))+(1/259)(0)+(1/306)(1-2)+(1/730)((2-3)+(2-1)) because 112 is the difference between current race date 1/1/2023 and last race date: 11/9/2022, and in the last race, student 1 ranked 2 while his competitor this race (namely student 2,3,4) ranked 3,1,NaN respectively, hence the first weight factor is (1/112)((2-3)+(2-1)+0) and so on and so forth

Here is a little excel to illustrate how I compute the new column:
[image]

I don't know of any fast way to do that.

I know it's quite complicated so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you are stuck with a big question, try to reduce it to smaller pieces.

First I will rephrase the question in smaller pieces, as I understood it. Because I do have some small deviations in the numbers compared to you, please verify that my understanding of the question is correct.

Secondly I will show the code that I used to solve the different pieces.

### In words

From your question, you are trying to perform a computation, based on all the students, that participate in the current race

Example: Take Race 1, Student 1:

- then his competitors in Race 1 are `2, 3, 4`.

Then you want to find all previous races where the main student competited against competitors from the current race. In otherwords: locate all previous races, where Student 1 and any of his competitors participated in.

Example: Take Race 1, Student 1, then their is:

- Race 2, with competitors 2 and 3
- Race 4, with competitor 2
- Race 5, with competitor 2 and 3

Race 3 doesn't count, since Student 1 didn't participated in it.

After this you want to compare the rank of the student in the previous race to the rank of his competitor in that same previous race.

Example: Take Race 1, Student 1, then their "competitor" score is a summation of:

- (1 / 112) * (2 - 3)
- (1 / 112) * (2 - 1)
- (1 / 306) * (1 - 2)
- (1 / 730) * (2 - 3)
- (1 / 730) * (2 - 1)

### In code

#### Preperation

Note that I change the date to a datetime object for comparison and added a column `Competitor`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, "1/1/2023", 1, 3],
    [1, "1/1/2023", 2, 2],
    [1, "1/1/2023", 3, 1],
    [1, "1/1/2023", 4, 4],
    [2, "11/9/2022", 1, 2],
    [2, "11/9/2022", 2, 3],
    [2, "11/9/2022", 3, 1],
    [3, "17/4/2022", 5, 4],
    [3, "17/4/2022", 2, 1],
    [3, "17/4/2022", 3, 2],
    [3, "17/4/2022", 4, 3],
    [4, "1/3/2022", 1, 1],
    [4, "1/3/2022", 2, 2],
    [5, "1/1/2021", 1, 2],
    [5, "1/1/2021", 2, 3],
    [5, "1/1/2021", 3, 1],
], columns=["Race_ID", "Date", "Student_ID", "Rank"])

df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda date: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
df['Competitor'] = 0
```

#### Step 1, locate competitors and races

By using pandas [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) I can give predicates such as `df['Race_ID'] == 1`, to filter information out of the dataframe.

```
for idx, (race, date, student, rank, _) in df.iterrows():
    this_race_competitors = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == race) & (df['Student_ID'] != student)]['Student_ID']
    other_races = df.loc[(df['Student_ID'] == student) & (df['Race_ID'] > race)][['Race_ID', 'Date', 'Rank']]
```

- `this_race_competitors` stores the ID's of all competitors in the main race.
- `other_races` stores the `Race ID`, `Date` and obtained `Rank` by the student of interest.

#### Step 2, locate other races with same competitors

With the race competitors and the other races known, we can combine this information to find the rank of all the competitors in the previous races.

```
competitor = 0
for prev_race, prev_date, prev_rank in other_races.values:
    other_ranks = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == prev_race) & df['Student_ID'].isin(this_race_competitors)]['Rank']
```

`other_ranks` stores all the competitors rank in the previous race

#### Step 3, calculate the competitor score

```
for competitor_rank in other_ranks:
    date_difference = (date - prev_date).days
    competitor += (1 / date_difference) * (prev_rank - competitor_rank)
    print(f"(1 / {date_difference}) * ({prev_rank} - {competitor_rank})")
```

## TL;DR

```
for idx, (race, date, student, rank, _) in df.iterrows():
    this_race_competitors = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == race) & (df['Student_ID'] != student)]['Student_ID']
    other_races = df.loc[(df['Student_ID'] == student) & (df['Race_ID'] > race)][['Race_ID', 'Date', 'Rank']]

    competitor = 0
    for prev_race, prev_date, prev_rank in other_races.values:
        other_ranks = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == prev_race) & df['Student_ID'].isin(this_race_competitors)]['Rank']

        for competitor_rank in other_ranks:
            date_difference = (date - prev_date).days
            competitor += (1 / date_difference) * (prev_rank - competitor_rank)
            print(f"(1 / {date_difference}) * ({prev_rank} - {competitor_rank})")

    df.loc[idx, 'Competitor'] = competitor

print(df)
```

Output

```
 Race_ID       Date  Student_ID  Rank  Competitor
       1 2023-01-01           1     3   -0.003268
       1 2023-01-01           2     2    0.022580
       1 2023-01-01           3     1   -0.030895
       1 2023-01-01           4     4    0.011583
       2 2022-09-11           1     2   -0.005155
       2 2022-09-11           2     3    0.003206
       2 2022-09-11           3     1    0.001948
       3 2022-04-17           5     4    0.000000
       3 2022-04-17           2     1    0.004246
       3 2022-04-17           3     2   -0.004246
       3 2022-04-17           4     3    0.000000
       4 2022-03-01           1     1   -0.002358
       4 2022-03-01           2     2    0.002358
       5 2021-01-01           1     2    0.000000
       5 2021-01-01           2     3    0.000000
       5 2021-01-01           3     1    0.000000
```

---

### Edit

In order to speed up the above code, we need to understand what is taking a lot of time. Looking at the code above ,ost of our time is lost in searching for the races and the specific competitors.

In other words, for every entry we have to check who are the competitor and in which other races have we both participate.

Because this is a very expensive search to do over and over again, it is better if we can precalculate all the participants per race, and which students participate in which races.

To make it more visually understanding for me I am using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to give a representation of the data that we are trying to catch.

```py
import datetime
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pprint import pprint


@dataclass
class Student:
    id: int
    race_ids: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)

    def shared_races(self, other) -> set:
        return set(self.race_ids).intersection(set(other.race_ids))


@dataclass
class Result:
    student: Student
    rank: int


@dataclass
class Race:
    id: int
    date: datetime.datetime
    results: list[Result] = field(default_factory=list)

    def competitors(self, student_id) -> list[Student]:
        return [result.student for result in self.results if result.student.id != student_id]

    def rank(self, student_id):
        for result in self.results:
            if student_id == result.student.id:
                return result.rank


def speedup(df):
    # Reorder the data, for faster access.
    races: dict[int, Race] = {}
    students: dict[int, Student] = {}

    for idx, (race_id, date, student_id, rank, score) in tqdm.tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=len(df)):
        student = students.get(student_id, Student(student_id))
        student.race_ids.append(race_id)
        students[student_id] = student

        race = races.get(race_id, Race(race_id, date))
        race.results.append(Result(student, rank))
        races[race_id] = race
    
    pprint(races)
    pprint(students)
```

```
# Output:

{1: Race(id=1,
         date=Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'),
         results=[Result(student=Student(id=1, race_ids=[1, 2, 4, 5]), rank=3),
                  Result(student=Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                         rank=2),
                  Result(student=Student(id=3, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5]), rank=1),
                  Result(student=Student(id=4, race_ids=[1, 3]), rank=4)]),
 2: Race(id=2,
         date=Timestamp('2022-09-11 00:00:00'),
         results=[Result(student=Student(id=1, race_ids=[1, 2, 4, 5]), rank=2),
                  Result(student=Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                         rank=3),
                  Result(student=Student(id=3, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5]), rank=1)]),
 3: Race(id=3,
         date=Timestamp('2022-04-17 00:00:00'),
         results=[Result(student=Student(id=5, race_ids=[3]), rank=4),
                  Result(student=Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                         rank=1),
                  Result(student=Student(id=3, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5]), rank=2),
                  Result(student=Student(id=4, race_ids=[1, 3]), rank=3)]),
 4: Race(id=4,
         date=Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'),
         results=[Result(student=Student(id=1, race_ids=[1, 2, 4, 5]), rank=1),
                  Result(student=Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                         rank=2)]),
 5: Race(id=5,
         date=Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
         results=[Result(student=Student(id=1, race_ids=[1, 2, 4, 5]), rank=2),
                  Result(student=Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                         rank=3),
                  Result(student=Student(id=3, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5]), rank=1)])
}

{1: Student(id=1, race_ids=[1, 2, 4, 5]),
 2: Student(id=2, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 3: Student(id=3, race_ids=[1, 2, 3, 5]),
 4: Student(id=4, race_ids=[1, 3]),
 5: Student(id=5, race_ids=[3])}
```

This gives us a way to quickly lookup which students partake in which race(s), and who are the competitors in every race.

In order to speed up the code even more we are going to use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to improve the speed even more.

```py
  def calculate_competitor(race_id, date, student_id, rank, _):
        this_student = students[student_id]
        competitor = 0

        for other_student in races[race_id].competitors(student_id):
            for other_race in this_student.shared_races(other_student):
                prev_race = races[other_race]
                day_difference = (date - prev_race.date).days
                if day_difference > 0:
                    competitor += (1 / day_difference * (prev_race.rank(student_id) - prev_race.rank(other_student.id)))

        return competitor

    # Go over the data to calculate the competitor score
    df['competitor'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_competitor(*row.values), axis=1)
```

The results should be the same, but around ~40x times faster.
Testing it on 20_000 entries takes about 2 seconds with my setup.

### TL;DR

##### Data generation

```py
import datetime
import random

import pandas as pd

def fake_db(entries=1_000):
    data = []

    race = 0
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    nr_of_students = max(entries // 10, 3)

    while len(data) < entries:
        # New race starts
        race += 1
        date -= datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 7))
        nr_of_participants = min(random.randint(3, 12), nr_of_students)

        # Create race results
        students = random.sample(range(1, nr_of_students + 1), k=nr_of_students)
        rank = random.sample(range(1, nr_of_participants + 1), k=nr_of_participants)

        for student_id, rank in zip(students, rank):
            data.append((race, f"{date.day}/{date.month}/{date.year}", student_id, rank))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data[:entries], columns=["Race_ID", "Date", "Student_ID", "Rank"])
    df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda date: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    df['Competitor'] = 0
    return df
```

##### Solution

```py
import datetime
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pprint import pprint

import tqdm


@dataclass
class Student:
    id: int
    race_ids: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)

    def shared_races(self, other) -> set:
        return set(self.race_ids).intersection(set(other.race_ids))


@dataclass
class Result:
    student: Student
    rank: int


@dataclass
class Race:
    id: int
    date: datetime.datetime
    results: list[Result] = field(default_factory=list)

    def competitors(self, student_id) -> list[Student]:
        return [result.student for result in self.results if result.student.id != student_id]

    def rank(self, student_id):
        for result in self.results:
            if student_id == result.student.id:
                return result.rank


def speedup(df):
    # Reorder the data, for faster access.
    races: dict[int, Race] = {}
    students: dict[int, Student] = {}

    for idx, (race_id, date, student_id, rank, score) in df.iterrows():
        student = students.get(student_id, Student(student_id))
        student.race_ids.append(race_id)
        students[student_id] = student

        race = races.get(race_id, Race(race_id, date))
        race.results.append(Result(student, rank))
        races[race_id] = race

    # pprint(races)
    # pprint(students)

    def calculate_competitor(race_id, date, student_id, rank, _):
        this_student = students[student_id]
        competitor = 0

        for other_student in races[race_id].competitors(student_id):
            for other_race in this_student.shared_races(other_student):
                prev_race = races[other_race]
                day_difference = (date - prev_race.date).days
                if day_difference > 0:
                    competitor += (1 / day_difference * (prev_race.rank(student_id) - prev_race.rank(other_student.id)))

        return competitor

    # Go over the data to calculate the competitor score
    df['competitor'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_competitor(*row.values), axis=1)

    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = fake_db(entries=10_000)
    df = speedup(df)

    df.to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and sorry it took so long for me to digest the code. However, my dataset is huge and it seems it takes too long to run the code. Is there any way to avoid the usage of ```for``` ? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So far for a consice answer... There is no real option to reduce a `for loop`, because of the way your data is stored. There are some options to perform some precalculations to reduce the amount of repeated searches that are performed. I updated the answer to include a faster solution, which mostly leverages a precalculation step. Also a small note on your comment, If possible try to provide measurable values for describing your database, since huge can be a thousand or a million entries. I am also still curious to see if there is a better way using table join.